# Read sound file in, add echo, and write new sound file

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, signal-processing

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

1. Read a sound file into memory
2. Divide it up into blocks and add an echo at a predefined offset (2 possible offset values).
3. Save as new file

I have the following code to read the sound file into memory:

```
NSURL   *urlToCAF = [NSURL URLWithString:@"simple-drum-beat.caf"];

ExtAudioFileRef caf;
OSStatus    status;

status = ExtAudioFileOpenURL((__bridge CFURLRef)urlToCAF, &caf);
if(noErr == status) {
    // request float format
    const UInt32 NumFrames = 1024;
    const int ChannelsPerFrame = 1;  // Mono, 2 for Stereo

    // request float format
    AudioStreamBasicDescription clientFormat;
    clientFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = ChannelsPerFrame;
    clientFormat.mSampleRate = 44100;

    clientFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    clientFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagIsFloat | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved; // float
    int cmpSize = sizeof(float);
    int frameSize = cmpSize*ChannelsPerFrame;
    clientFormat.mBitsPerChannel = cmpSize*8;
    clientFormat.mBytesPerPacket = frameSize;
    clientFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    clientFormat.mBytesPerFrame = frameSize;

    status = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(caf, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof(clientFormat), &clientFormat);
    if(noErr != status) { /* handle it */ }

    while(1) {
        float   buf[ChannelsPerFrame*NumFrames];
        AudioBuffer ab = { ChannelsPerFrame, sizeof(buf), buf };
        AudioBufferList abl;
        abl.mNumberBuffers = 1;
        abl.mBuffers[0] = ab;

        UInt32  ioNumFrames = NumFrames;
        status = ExtAudioFileRead(caf, &ioNumFrames, &abl);

        if(noErr == status) {
            // do something here
        }
    }

    // later
    status = ExtAudioFileDispose(caf);
    if(noErr != status) { /* hmm */ }
}
```

Can you please provide me with the necessary code to add in echoes into each block and then to save the sound as a new file?

I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This is bordering on "please write my code for me"

Putting in an echo is trivial, if you have the sound waves in a buffer:

```
out[k] = in[k] + in[k-30]
```

Saving to file I'm pretty sure you can find with Google. Try to make your questions ask about one specific thing.

I recommend looking into http://theamazingaudioengine.com/ -- it makes life much easier!